# link multi textview to single webview

Tags: android, android-webview

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView textview,textView5;/* My textviews*/

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Amazon.class);
                    startActivity(intent);/* to connect webview in the next intent*/
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Amazon.class);
                    intent3.putExtra("webviewurl", webviewurl);
                    startActivity(intent3);

                }
            });
            textView5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
           textView5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Amazon.class);
                   startActivity(intent1);/* to start the intent*/
               }
           });

        }

}
```

I need to know how multiple text view are link to the single web view in the next activity with different web address.

Comment: By next activity code is public class Amazon extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.amazon);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.amazon.in");
    }
}

Comment: hey please explain what you want

Comment: i am using multi textviews and link it webview in next activity if i use above my activity list is increasing so i need to know how multi textview can be linked to single webview in nextactivity do u get me sonu

Comment: you want to give intent to from textview to the webview ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following this sample :

main_activity.layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text 3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView textview1,textview2,textview3,textView5;/* My textviews*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Amazon.class);
                intent1.putExtra("webviewurl", "your URL for Textview 1");
                startActivity(intent1);

            }
        });

       textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Amazon.class);
                intent1.putExtra("webviewurl", "your URL for Textview 2");
                startActivity(intent1);
           }
       });

        textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
       textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Amazon.class);
                intent1.putExtra("webviewurl", "your URL for Textview 3");
                startActivity(intent1);
           }
       });
    }
```

and in class Amazon , add this code at `onCreate`

```
String mURL =  getIntent().getStringExtra("webviewurl");
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(mURL);
```

Comment: sorry sonu kumar this is not actually my question in a little confusion i entered  this is my correct code: textview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Amazon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
      <WebView
android:id="@+id/webView" />  now tell me how to link multi textview to this webview and it should be open in appliction only